# Put labels in Coolprop Chart

Tags: python, r, charts, python-3.8, diagram

Following the idea of Sino-Atrial Node ([link](https://groups.google.com/g/coolprop-users/c/pp6SH3C9zaY)):

```
from CoolProp.Plots import PropertyPlot

plot = PropertyPlot("Water", 'Ph')
plot.calc_isolines()
ax = plot.axis
ax.text(2000, 100, ' 1', fontsize=10, rotation=45, color='r')
plot.show()
```

[image]

I try to reproduce it, to introduce labels in the Coolprop chart in these lines of code, but without result.

Any idea how to achieve this goal?
It is possible to improve the code. Improvements and changes will be welcome.

These are the lines of code:

```
#pyimport("sys").executable
from numpy import shape as size 
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from CoolProp import CoolProp as CP
from CoolProp.Plots import PropertyPlot as CPP #StateContainer
from CoolProp.Plots import SimpleCompressionCycle as CPPSCC

TT =( [[55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55],
[33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49]])

n=size(TT)[1]

for i in range(size(TT)[1]):
 pp = CPP("R32", "PH", unit_system="KSI")
 #pp.title("R32 log p-h Diagramm_"+str(i))
 pp.set_axis_limits([-40, 700, 0, 15000])
 pp.xlabel("h [kJ/kg]")
 pp.ylabel("P [kPa]")
 pp.calc_isolines(CP.iQ, num=11)
 cycle = CPPSCC("R32", "PH", unit_system="KSI")
 T0 = TT[1][i]+273.15
 pp.state.update(CP.QT_INPUTS,0.0,T0-0.02) 
 p0 = pp.state.keyed_output(CP.iP)
 T2 = TT[0][i]+273.15
 pp.state.update(CP.QT_INPUTS,1.0,T2+0.02)
 p2 = pp.state.keyed_output(CP.iP)
 pp.calc_isolines(CP.iT, [T0 ,T2 ], num=2)
 pp.props[CP.iT]['color'] = 'green'
 pp.props[CP.iT]['lw'] = '0.5'
 txt ="T0 {:.2f}K /P0 {:.2f}MPa \n T2 {:.2f}K /P2 {:.2f}MPa".format(T0,p0/1e6,T2,p2/1e6)        
 pp.title("R32 log p-h Diagramm \n "+txt)
 
 pa=0.996424*100000
 h=CP.PropsSI("H","P",pa,"T",T0,"R32")
 
 cycle.simple_solve(T0, p0, T2, p2, 0.7, SI=True)
 cycle.steps =50
 sc = cycle.get_state_changes()
 #label 1
 pp.draw_process(sc,line_opts={'color':'blue', 'lw':1.5})
 pp.grid()
 ax = pp.axis
 lb1="{:.2f}K".format(T0)
 ax.text(h, pa, lb1, fontsize=10, rotation=45, color='r')

 plt.close(cycle.figure)
 pp.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my example, shown above, the labels cannot be displayed because the calculation units do not match those of the graph.
To be able to visualize the units and values use the property: _cycle_states.

```
from numpy import shape as size 
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from CoolProp import CoolProp as CP
from CoolProp.Plots import PropertyPlot as CPP #StateContainer
from CoolProp.Plots import SimpleCompressionCycle as CPPSCC

import matplotlib.transforms as mtransforms


TT =( [[55, 55, 55, 55, 55],
    [33, 34, 35, 36, 37]])

n=size(TT)[1]

for i in range(size(TT)[1]):
 pp = CPP("R32", "PH", unit_system="KSI")
 #pp.title("R32 log p-h Diagramm_"+str(i))
 pp.set_axis_limits([-40, 700, 0, 15000])
 pp.xlabel("h [kJ/kg]")
 pp.ylabel("P [kPa]")
 pp.calc_isolines(CP.iQ, num=11)
 cycle = CPPSCC("R32", "PH", unit_system="KSI")
 T0 = TT[1][i]+273.15
 pp.state.update(CP.QT_INPUTS,0.0,T0-0.02) 
 p0 = pp.state.keyed_output(CP.iP)
 T2 = TT[0][i]+273.15
 pp.state.update(CP.QT_INPUTS,1.0,T2+0.02)
 p2 = pp.state.keyed_output(CP.iP)
 pp.calc_isolines(CP.iT, [T0 ,T2 ], num=2)
 pp.props[CP.iT]['color'] = 'green'
 pp.props[CP.iT]['lw'] = '0.5'   
 pp.title("R32 log p-h Diagramm ")
 
 cycle.simple_solve(T0, p0, T2, p2, 0.7, SI=True)
 cycle.steps =50
 sc = cycle.get_state_changes()
 pp.draw_process(sc,line_opts={'color':'blue', 'lw':1.5})
 pp.grid()
 #View the values and units used in the calculation 
 print(cycle._cycle_states)
 #LABELS
 fig = pp.figure
 ax = pp.axis
 trans_offset = mtransforms.offset_copy(ax.transData, fig=fig,
                                       x=-0.12, y=0.10, units='inches')
 
 #label 1
 T0=cycle._cycle_states[0,"T"]
 pa=0.996424#Pressure value selected to place the labels
 h=CP.PropsSI("H","P",pa,"T",T0,"R32")/1000
 lb1="{:.2f}K".format(T0)
 ax.text(h, pa, lb1, fontsize=10, rotation=90, color='r',transform=trans_offset,horizontalalignment='left',verticalalignment='baseline')
 #label 2
 T2=cycle._cycle_states[2,"T"]
 pa=0.996424##Pressure value selected to place the labels
 h=CP.PropsSI("H","P",pa,"T",T2,"R32")/1000
 lb2="{:.2f}K".format(T2)
 ax.text(h, pa, lb2, fontsize=10, rotation=90, color='r',transform=trans_offset,horizontalalignment='left',verticalalignment='baseline')

 #Pressures
 trans_offset = mtransforms.offset_copy(ax.transData, fig=fig,
                                       x=0, y=0.02, units='inches')
 #label p1
 p0=cycle._cycle_states[0,"P"]/1000
 h03=(sum(cycle._cycle_states.H[[0,3]])/2)/1000
 lbp0="{:.2f}KPa".format(p0)
 ax.text(h03, p0, lbp0, fontsize=10, rotation=0, color='b',horizontalalignment='center',transform=trans_offset)
 #label p2
 p1=cycle._cycle_states[1,"P"]/1000
 h12=(sum(cycle._cycle_states.H[[1,2]])/2)/1000
 lbp1="{:.2f}KPa".format(p1)
 ax.text(h12, p1, lbp1, fontsize=10, rotation=0, color='b',horizontalalignment='center',transform=trans_offset)
 
 plt.close(cycle.figure)
 pp.show()
```

The results are shown in the graph.
[image]

[image]